# How to pull the next row adddate where there is condition match from using sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to pull the add_date of code where code = next code..for ex:- I have code '25' which comes for the same case  multiple times ....but for every time I need check what is the next_code and pull the next_code's add_date.. any insight would greatly helps

[image: below is the data]
[image: expected output]

Comment: what is your expected output? None of these records have your case, `where Code = Next_code` so it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No worries, just add it to the original question (edit your question)

Comment: i have just added the expected output...basically from the highlighted records...i need to put in in single row